# Mongoose: Child document does not update on parent document update

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I've been on this problem for quite a while. I have 2 schemas:

```
**The User Schema**

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PaymentSchema = require('../models/payments').schema;
const UserSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
firstname :{
    type  : String,
    required : true
} ,
lastname :{
    type  : String,
    required : true
} ,
email :{
    type  : String,
    required : true
} ,
country :{
    type  : String,
    required : true
} ,
state :{
    type  : String,
    required : true
} ,
city :{
    type  : String,
    required : true
} ,
postal :{
    type  : String,
    required : true
} ,
phone :{
    type  : String,
    required : true
} ,
plan :{
    type  : String,
} ,
amount :{
    type  : String,
} ,
profit:{
    type: String,
},
amountDue:{
    type: String,
},
password :{
    type  : String,
    required : true
} ,
withdrawals :[PaymentSchema],

payDate :{
    type : Date,
    default : Date.now
},
date :{
    type : Date,
    default : Date.now
}
});
const User= mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

The payments Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PaymentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String
    },
    lastname:{
        type: String
    },
    balance:{
        type: String
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    paid: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
    userid:{
        type: String
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

});

const Payment = mongoose.model('Payment', PaymentSchema);

module.exports = Payment;
```

The logic is this: When a user makes payment, a POST request is sent and the information from the payment request is displayed on an admin dashboard. The POST request looks like this:

```
router.post('/users/:id/payments', function (req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, fuser) {
        if (err) {
            req.flash('error_msg', 'Something went wrong. Please login and try again')
            res.redirect('/logout')
        } else {
            var pay = new Payment({
                firstname: fuser.firstname,
                lastname: fuser.lastname,
                balance: fuser.amount,
                amount: req.body.usd,
                address: req.body.to,
                paid: false,
                userid: fuser.id
            })
            pay.save(function (err, pays) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, userr) {
                        userr.withdrawals.push(pays)
                        userr.save(function (err, user) {
                            if (err) {
                                req.flash('error_msg', 'Something went wrong. Please login and try again')
                                res.redirect('/logout')
                            } else {
                                res.redirect('/dashboard')
                            }
                        })
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

The information sent to the admin dashboard is then approved and the admin makes a PUT request to that particular payment, updating the "paid" property to "true". Like so:

```
router.put('/admin/withdrawals/:id', function (req, res) {
    var update = {
        paid: true
    }
    Payment.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, update, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.send("error!")
        } else {
            User.findById(user.userid, function (err, uza) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send("error!")
                } else {
                    var amount = uza.amount
                    var deduct = req.body.aamount
                    var balance = parseInt(amount) - parseInt(deduct)
                    var updated = {
                        amount: balance,
                    }
                    User.findByIdAndUpdate(user.userid, updated, function (err, pays) {
                        if (err) {
                            res.send(err)
                        } else {
                            req.flash('success_msg', 'Withdrawal has been confirmed!')
                            res.redirect('/admin/dashboard')
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

The payment document gets updated to "true" but the embedded payment document on the User Schema still remains "false".

Please what do I need to do to update the paid property from "false" to "true" on both the main payment document and on the embedded payment document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link between the schemas like so:

`withdrawals: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Payment' }],`

Otherwise you have to update the data in both schemas manually!

See the docs here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-ref

Comment: I actually fixed it. Thank you